# dependency "androidx.core:core-ui" not found

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, androidx

When adding constraint layout group to my project, Android studio auto add the dependency in gradle:

> implementation 'androidx.core:core-ui:+'

But I've got this error message:

> Failed to resolve: androidx.core:core-ui:+

I couldn't find any way to add corresponding androidx dependency, the only solution I know so far is using support lib but It against the guideline to move everything to androidx.

> com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0

Is there any androix dependency which includes the ConstraintLayout Group?

Answer (score 3):

Use this in your app gradle file instead...

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your build.gradle file `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'`
constraint layout does not show up for me to drag it into the layout editor(3.2 canary) but I can use it by writing the code in xml and adding this library. For any other dependencies, try writing the specific dependency in gradle, it appears core-ui for androidx not working yet.

Edit:

There should be a download icon next to the dependencies you don't have. You can click on it and there will be a pop up stating the dependency name. In Studio 3.2 Canary on windows, it is not adding these dependencies automatically, which is why my solution is to implement the dependency in `build.gradle` manually.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the problem. I already put the constraintLayout:1.1.0 in my Gradle but I want to use ConstraintLayout Group which seems like not inside constraintlayout v1.1.0 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group. You can try to add a group in constraintlayout to see what will happen in Android Studio.

Comment: I believe Android team will put core-ui into androidx soon